# How does drops do this div animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I've stumbled upon this site called Drops, can't figure out how they do the div animation when a user scrolls up/down. How could they be doing this animation, what library can it be done with or is pure CSS enough?

[Drops](https://languagedrops.com/#learn-through-visuals)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They using Midnight.js,
here is the link for the library - http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/